# What is the difference among pip.exe, pip3.exe and pip3.8.exe?

Tags: python, pip

I found these three in C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts

What is the difference among them?

[pip files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgXCk.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would have checked their size and their content you would have recognized that all files are equal (same size, same content).

There are 3 versions because some scripts, tutorials, .. use a Python-version specific pip command (e.g. for pip of Python v3.x or v3.8) other a version unspecific pip version.

On Linux a Python installation uses soft-links for providing the different versions. On Windows for three separate files are used. Most likely because not all Windows file-systems support soft links.